# mysql query for select from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.

We have two mysql tables.

What I'm doing is taking all the details in the first table and feeding it to an html page to let all users to view it. But now I want to add some details from a second table related to a column in first table.

I mean, I have a column in first table call "Pending_on" in that column I have inserted some branch names 
and in the second table I have inserted the contact details of those departments.

So, if we think in the first table fifth row pending_on column has the value "HR" then I want to display the telephone number of the HR department.

So, how can I write a query for this?

Comment: What you need is join query, you can find more information here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: actually i don't know how to do that. can you please tel me how ?

Answer (score 2):

For your case, here is an example:

There are 2 tables named **entry** and **subscription**.

```
      entry
        field1    publisherId
        field2    entry

      subscription
        field1   myId
        field2   friendId
```

You can use a **JOIN**. In plain SQL:

```
SELECT e.publisherId, e.entry
FROM entry e
JOIN subscription s
ON s.friendId = e.publisherId
WHERE s.myId = 1234
```

Comment: can i use this without Where clue?

Comment: Yes, but it will get more than one row.

Comment: yes definitely u can use join query without where clause, however it will result in multiple records!

Comment: This should cover it, but you probably want a LEFT OUTER JOIN to bring back rows from the first table even if there is no matching pending record

Comment: @kickstart- yes i'm searching some thing like that. i want to bring rows either there is no matching records. 
can you kindly tel me how to change above code to this?

Comment: i wrote this still nothing on the var_dump
 SELECT n.emp_name, n.emp_number
          FROM new_users n
          LEFT OUTER JOIN contact c
          ON n.pending_on = c.dep

Comment: That code should do it. Have you tried it directly on the database (ie, through phpmyadmin or the like)? Although you probably need to output the fields from the contact table as well (if there is no matching row those fields will have a value of NULL)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your example. You have a column name pending_on in your first table, and in your second table you have your department_name column. Find the below code for joining those two tables,

```
$this->db->select('firsttable.*,secondtable.contact_details');
$this->db->from('firsttable');
$this->db->join('secondtable', 'firsttable.pending_on = secondtable.department_name','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

So, The department_name in second table and pending_on in first table should have the same value as you mentioned "HR". And my suggestion is to have the id's of the table as reference instead of department names. Hope This helps.

Comment: this is working but if there is no matching items in both tables this query doesn't give me any thing. but what i want is i need to take all the rows of first table if there is or no matching items in both

Comment: $this->db->join('secondtable', 'firsttable.pending_on = secondtable.department_name','left');

Hope this will satisfy your condition!! :)

Comment: **`$this->db->join('secondtable', 'firsttable.pending_on = secondtable.department_name','left');`** Hope this will satisfy your condition!! :)

Comment: this query did my work 
Thank You Mr.Yuvaraj Bathrabagu 
$this->db->join('contact', 'new_users.pending_on = contact.dep','left');

Answer (score 1):

this is the query i used to do my work

and thanks goes to MR. Yuvvaraj Bathrabagu

$this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('new_users');
      $this->db->join('contact', 'new_users.pending_on = contact.dep','left');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $data = $query->result_array();